# Transfer data from Ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to send datas from ajax to php, but php doesnt show it. both scripts are on the same site: "testpage.php".

jQuery/Ajax:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {

      var test = "bla";
      $.ajax({
        url: "testpage.php",
        type: "post",
        data: test,
        success: function (response) {
          alert("test ok");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
      <?php
        if(isset($_POST["test"])) {
          $test2 = $_POST;
          echo $test2;
          echo "Test";
        }
      ?>
```

I do not see the result of PHP

Comment: `data: {test:test},`

Comment: use data: {test:test}, & alert your response to see your result.
success: function (response) {
          alert(response);
        },

Or Just append your response to html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: With using data: {test:test}, my response is my whole HTML/PHP-code. is this correct?

Comment: When will finally all questions about sending data from ajax to PHP be answered? It's like 5 questions a day...

Comment: @Chpo7234 you should not get HTML in your response. You should only see the value of `$test2` and the string `"Test"`. Are you still getting those bad results?

Comment: No, thank you! Works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `data: {test:test},` & alert your response to see your result.

```
success: function (response) {
   alert(response);
},
```

Or Just `append` your response to `html`.

Comment: Response shows my whole html-code. is this correct?

Comment: response should be your content which you echo, print or return in "testpage.php".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `data: {test:sometext}` if you want to do a `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP can't see the value in the post because you only send `bla` in the PHP body. You have to send `test=bla`. But jQuery can do it automatically by sending `data : { test : test }`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {

        var test = "bla";
        $.ajax({
            url: "testpage.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                test : test
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert("test ok");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize() method into your $.ajax();

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "testpage.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $("#myForm input").serialize(),
    success: function (response) {
      alert("test ok");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

Then try to accessing your post data by form input name.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var data = {
        'test':  "bla",
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testpage.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
```